# Trying to switch dapp to MATIC

Tags: dapps, json-rpc, polygon

I'm trying to switch a dapp to MATIC/Polygon.
I get this strange error:
Something went wrong: Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
"details": "Unauthorized method: net_listening.",
"code": -32005
}

My code is like this:

```
 App = {
                web3Provider: null,
            


            init: function() {
                return App.initWeb3();
            },

            initWeb3: function() {
                if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
                    App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
                    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
                } else {
                    App.web3Provider = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'wss://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com/ws/v1/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); // 
                    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
                }
                            
                web3.eth.net.getId().then(netId => {
                    switch (netId) {
                        case 137:
                            break
                        default:
                          $('#div_wrong_network').show()
                    }
                });
                
                getAccounts(function(result) {
                    App.account = result[0];    
                });
                
                return App.initContracts();
            },

            initContracts: function() {$.getJSON("../XXXX.json", function(Response) {
                    var abi = Response.abi;
                    
                            App.listenForEvents();
                            return App.render();
                        
                        }
                    
            },
            
            listenForEvents: function() {
                ...
            },

            render: async function() {
                if (App.loading) {
                  return;
                }
                App.loading = true;
                
                if(ethereum.selectedAddress !== null)
                {
                    web3.eth.net.isListening()
                   .then(() => {})
                   .catch(e => console.log('Something went wrong: '+ e));
                    
                    if(window.ethereum) {
                        await ethereum.enable();
                    }
                }
```

....

Looks like web3.eth.net.isListening() is failing. What could be the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in the Infura docs, might be helpful:
[image: JSON-RPC error codes]

It seems like the error 32005 indicates that you're exceeding some predefined limit on the number of requests that the node/server allows you to make?

Hope that helps.